# How can I reverse the input text in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a project where i want to turn the input text to right to left
I tried using Dir="rtl" but it only moves the text to right.
what I want is when somebody press 1 and then 2 the input field shows 21
can I get some help??

Comment: What does this have to do with node.js? That runs on the server, not the browser.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: https://codepen.io/jafri_ali/pen/bGMKajJ

Comment: Post it here, not at codepen. I gave you the link to the Stack Snippet instructions.

Comment: Add `unicode-bidi:bidi-override;`